# How do you remove an inflated menu/items from the new Lollipop Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-menu, android-toolbar

I include a v7 Toolbar in my layout.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    />
```

I'm inflating a menu into it with the following:

```
mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.options_add_contact);
```

Now how do I know remove/reset it? I've tried a couple shots in the dark:

- inflating an empty menu
- `mToolbar.inflateMenu(0)`
- `moolbar.setMenu(null, null)`
- `toolbar.setMenu(null, null)`

Answer (score 129, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if this is what you mean nor have tried it but.

```
mToolbar.getMenu().clear();
```

should clear the menu.

I have still been using `onCreateOptionsMenu` for all my menu creation however