# I want to remove the optionMenu when there are no items in ListView (emptyView is shown)?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-optionsmenu

I have an app that adds items to an sqlite database and returns a cursor, this cursor is then used with a custom CursorAdapter called StoreCursorAdapter to show the items in a ListView.

There is a (delete all) button as an optionsMenuItem.

I want to hide this optionsMenuItem when no items are avaliable in the ListView.

[InventoryActivty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPl7p.png)

[EditorActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDigC.png)

Sorry for the links I am a new user so they don't allow me to embed images yet. :-(

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventory);

    //Declare the views
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);

    //Set the screen to be shown when there are no list items
    list.setEmptyView(emptyView);

    //StoreCursorAdapter is a custom CursorAdapter
    mAdapter = new StoreCursorAdapter(this, null);
    list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu options from the res/menu/menu_inventory.xml file.
    // This adds menu items to the app bar.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_inventory, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // User clicked on a menu option in the app bar overflow menu
    showDeleteConfirmationDialog();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I tried

1 - emptyView.visibilty() == View.INVISBLE

2 - list.getAdapter == null

but they didn't work

What statement will do the job?!

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        if (//what statement) {
            MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_delete_all);
            menuItem.setVisible(false);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Note:

OnStart() gets called after I get back from the EditorActivity

Note:

In my app I can delete individual items from another activity so adding invalidateOptionsMenu(); in the onOptionsItemSelected won't do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct condition to put inside `onPrepareOptionsMenu` is:

```
menuItem.setVisible(!mAdapter.isEmpty());
```

that is the same comparison the ListView uses manages the empty view (minus null check) (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/AdapterView.java#747)

but I believe there's another issue here, is that the data is changing after the activity started, during `showDeleteConfirmationDialog()`. That means you have to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` the moment the data is changed. There're two ways of doing it. One more robust and the other is faster to code:

1. faster to code (but not very good/clean):

add `invalidateOptionsMenu()` after the code that executes the DB operations.

2. more robust/clean

you'll use start/stop callbacks to listen to changes in the data. Something like the following:

```
@Override protected void onStart(){
  super.onStart();
  invalidateOptionsMenu();
  mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(dataObserver);
}

@Override protected void onStop(){
  mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(dataObserver);
  super.onStop();
}

private final DataSetObserver dataObserver = new DataSetObserver(){
  @Override public void onChanged(){
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
  }
  @Override public void onInvalidated(){
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
  }
};
```

all code above was typed by heart, there're likely typos, but that's the idea and the typos you can fix later at your code.

Comment: And A BIG Thank you from The Deep of my Heart. You were right about that error and I kinda prefer to use the more clean/robust method, for example a more clean method for responding to a click event is using an OnClickListener instead of (android:onclick) xml tag.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont have any menu item to show, why are u inflating one, if you dont inflate you wont.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return false;
}
```

Unless you need to dynamically remove the menu options based on the current state of the activity, this might help [How do you remove an inflated menu/items from the new Lollipop Toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789315/how-do-you-remove-an-inflated-menu-items-from-the-new-lollipop-toolbar)

Comment: I want to show the menu if there are items shown and hide the menu if there were no items